# Using zurb foundation, I'm looking to use the clearing lightbox function without having to use the thumbnail formatting

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, lightbox

I'm aiming to make use of the [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) image handler ["clearing lightbox"](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html) for a small group of images on a site **without** the default formatting that comes with it. In fact, Im using the [seamless responsive photo grid](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/) to format the images, hence my current dilemma.

Ideally, this would be a foundation-based solution so I can keep my dependencies to a minimum.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I may have psyched myself here. It turns out all it took was modifying a single css class and following the protocol.

*Sorry SO for wasting disk space* : [

> In an attempt to make this waste-of-a-post worth something, all that is needed is:

```
.clearing-thumbs li{  
  float: none;
  margin: 0;  
}
```

I suppose one other thing worth noting is that it is important to have the unordered list tag formatted properly: `<ul class="clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>`  I believe that is what sent me off on this tangent. Without those two things, the lightbox doesn't appear to activate whatsoever.